# Windows Virtual Desktop - resource isn't visible

Tags: azure

I've created a Windows virtual desktop pool, but my user can't see the resource when they log in to https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/webclient

Comment: The error is "It looks like your Admin hasn't set up any resources for you yet. Try again later or contact your admin."

Answer (score 0):

Have you [Assign additional users to the desktop application group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/create-host-pools-azure-marketplace#optional-assign-additional-users-to-the-desktop-application-group)?

Run the following cmdlet to sign in to the Windows Virtual Desktop environment:

```
Add-RdsAccount -DeploymentUrl "https://rdbroker.wvd.microsoft.com"
```

Add users to the desktop application group by using this cmdlet:

```
Add-RdsAppGroupUser <tenantname> <hostpoolname> "Desktop Application Group" -UserPrincipalName <userupn>
```

After you've completed these steps, **users added to the desktop application group can** sign in to Windows Virtual Desktop with supported Remote Desktop clients and **see a resource for a session desktop**.

Also you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/troubleshoot-client-connection) to troubleshoot.

Comment: Joey, when I run that command, I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuUUx.png

Comment: Joey, I found a mismatch in Tenantname, I resolved that and was able to see the resource. But when connecting, I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHrzo.png

Comment: or can it be because my domain is in a different resource group then my VM?

Comment: I tried creating it all from scratch, but deployment fails at the join domain step - with a status of conflict